# IIS hosting WCF service error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I am using IIS 7.0 to host a simple WCF service. I write it by using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C#. The issue is when I access http://localhost:9999/service.svc (I suppose in web browser we can browse the content of WSDL, and I create a new web site which uses port 9999 and run application pool under administrator account), I am met with the following error, any ideas what is wrong?

http://i27.tinypic.com/a9r8cz.jpg

Here is my service.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="Gu.WCF.StudentManagement" %>
```

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Gu.WCF.ServiceBehavior"
        name="Gu.WCF.StudentManagement">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Gu.WCF.IStudentManagement">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Gu.WCF.ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the .NET 3.0 ISAPI mappings have vanished. In the .NET 3.0 WCF directory (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation) run ServiceModelReg -r

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have the .svc extension mapped to the ISAPI handler.

Comment: Thanks, if I need to access WSDL file from browser, I need to access the .svc file?

Comment: Yes, to get the WSDL, you will need to hit the service (access the .svc) file and the service host class will then assemble the WSDL from its service description.